# AWS EC2 Scheduling Tasks with Windows Scheduler

Tags: amazon-ec2, job-scheduling

If I have a Amazon Redshift instance and an Amazon EC2 instance (running windows amongst other things), can I set up windows scheduled jobs in the EC2 instance that connects to Redshift and runs copy commands?

Really what I am asking is 'is EC2 just a VM on the cloud' and can I do anything I like in it (like set up windows scheduled jobs and be guaranteed they will run on a scheduled time)

It seems that AWS data pipeline is the recommended way to have scheduled jobs load data into Resdshift but this starts to get pricey with frequent jobs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran up a redshift instance and a EC2 windows 2012 instance

I installed the ODBC redshift driver

I ran a VBScript that incremented a counter in a table

I scheduled that script in task scheduler

I logged out of EC2 and came back and the data was updated.

So it seems that using windows scheduler on EC2 is a valid alternative to AWS data pipeline of you want to do it that way.

I haven't yet tried the copy command but I will come back and document that also if I have time